# This application does not exist - GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This application is live. I previously used this project for php, now I am experimenting with Java and I cannot get the project to upload. Below is the error message I get:

> com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to
>   URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=laraveltest2014&version=1&
>   404 Not Found This application does not exist
>   (app_id=u'laraveltest2014').

I tried adding the parameter below and it had no effect.

--no_cookies

Comment: Can you try to set your app as s~laraveltest2014 in app.yaml / appengine-web.xml and try to deploy again?

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in with different google account previously, try deleting these two files from home directory:

```
.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java 
.appcfg_cookies
```